# Grails 2: High memory usage org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl

Tags: hibernate, memory, grails, jvm

I am working on a **Grails 2.5.2** based application. When I start the application, the memory usage is normal. But, over time, it keeps on increasing. I am not able to figure out what might be causing that. When I tried analyzing the heap dump through **Eclipse MAT**, the dominator tree looked like this:

[image: Dominator_tree]

Did someone face similar problem before? Could it be an internal leak of Hibernate? Or, could it be a problem in code?

**Edit**: Why I am thinking that it could be internal is, if I understand it correctly, the sessionFactory and queryPlanCache objects are nested, they are not all at root level.

Answer (score 0):

Your QueryPlan cache is probably just too big for the available memory on your JVM. Alter the default size as described here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-query